# Forcing user to enter one entry from two options not to write it together

Tags: vba

i have two text boxes : percentage and txtamount
i want to force user to enter percentage or amount not to write it together 
casue if he did entered % and amount it makes some problems with me as i have alot of formulas
thanks

What I have tried:

```
privite sub post_click()
If (Me.percentage.Value >= 0 And Me.txtamount.Value >= 0) Then MsgBox " You should select % or amount ": Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that one (and only one) of your two textboxes has a value in it, use the following:

```
Private Sub post_Click()
    If Not (Me.percentage.Value = "" Xor Me.txtamount.Value = "") Then MsgBox "You should select % or amount": Exit Sub
```

Testing for `>= 0` won't work if the textbox is empty (because `"" >= 0` will give a type mismatch). Testing for whether the textbox is `""` will give a better indication of whether data has been entered.

Using `Xor` (which returns `True` iff one operand is `True` and the other is `False`) will therefore determine whether only one textbox has been filled in and the other left empty, and the `Not` will display the message if that is not the case.